# SMTP Mail not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, sendmail

I'm trying to send mail on intranet. I have designed a page where the values will be accepted from textboxes, and passed to the respective fields.

This is my front end code (Please ignore the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags):

```
<td>
    FROM
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1" Width="414px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    SENDER MAIL
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMailAdd" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1" Width="414px"></asp:TextBox>
<td>
    SMTP IP
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSMTP" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1" Width="414px"></asp:TextBox>
<td>
   RECEIVER
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReceiver" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1" Width="414px"></asp:TextBox>
<td>
    TO MAIL
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox1" Width="414px"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is my backend code:

```
protected void btnSMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string smtpadd = txtSMTP.Text;

    try
    {
        if (smtpadd != "" && smtpadd != null)
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(txtSMTP.Text);

            if (!fupAttach.HasFile)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\DEV\\New.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                Attachment attch = new Attachment(fs, "License Generation in XML", MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                mm.Attachments.Add(attch);
            }

            //sc.Host = "10.8.4.118";
            sc.Port = 25;
            sc.EnableSsl = false; // runtime encrypt the SMTP communications using SSL

            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtTo.Text, txtReceiver.Text));
            mm.From = new MailAddress(txtMailAdd.Text, txtFrom.Text);
            mm.Subject = txtSub.Text;
            //mm.To= new MailAddress(txtTo.Text);
            mm.Body = txtBody.Text;

            if (fupAttach.HasFile)
            {
                String FileName = fupAttach.PostedFile.FileName;
                Attachment mailAttachment = new Attachment(FileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                mm.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment); 
            }

            lblMailFail.Text = "Mail Successfully Sent";

            sc.Send(mm);
        }

        else
        {
            lblMailFail.Text = "Enter an SMTP IP";
        }
    }
```

Now when I try to enter the following values in the textbox

```
Sender Mail: xyz@sdc.ba.co.in
SMTP ID: 10.8.4.2
Receiver Mail: xyz@sdc.ba.co.in
```

I get an error

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for xyz@sdc.ba.co.in at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at Lic_Gen.btnSMail_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)`

Can someone please guide me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Ensure that you use the right smtp port.

Comment: The SMTP server does not allow relaying (i.e. forward the email to another server). You either have to configure the SMTP server to allow relaying or switch to another one.

Comment: Though as a point, don't say it's successfully sent before you send it. Also put it in a try catch to allow for the fact the mail server could go down and if that happens then this code will just break.

Answer (score 2):

This is an SMTP configuration issue and nothing to do with your C# code.

Comment: so my code is perfectly fine then? :P

Comment: I wouldn't say it's perfect, but yes, it will work if the SMTP config is correct :D

Comment: :P haha. okay. thanks. and how will i check whether my SMTP config is correct or not? :P

Comment: @Syrion: yes, the key info is in the server response `Unable to relay for ...`, the problem must be that the mail server is not configured for accepting messages for users from the domain of the mail recipient.

Answer (score 2):

The mail server does not allow you (or your IP) to send mail to the specified e-mail address. You can do a detailed test of the mailserver [here](https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server).

You can find more information on mail relay on the [Eudora website](http://www.eudora.com/techsupport/kb/1593hq.html) (most of the info applies to all mail servers)